# Is it possible to port an OSX Screensaver into Linux?

Tags: macos, screensaver, port, xscreensaver

Is it possible to port an OSX Screensaver into Linux? Specifically this one called "[ScreenMazer](https://github.com/dado3212/ScreenMazer)" which is freely available from github.

I know that `xscreensaver` has a maze of their own, but the one made for OSX looks infinitely better than that one. I especially like the built-in clock that the one from `xscreensaver` lacks.

I'm not very confident there's an easy way to do it, but it can't hurt to ask, right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it’s always possible to port a piece of software from one platform to another, but the effort involved varies. In ScreenMazer’s case, the following issues make this endeavour somewhat complex:

- there is no license, so changing ScreenMazer or creating a derivative of it is illegal;
- while there is [a Swift compiler and library for Linux](https://swift.org/blog/swift-linux-port/), it doesn’t support two frameworks which ScreenMazer makes heavy use of: [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit), which is Metal-specific, and the `ScreenSaver` support.

Regarding the former, if ScreenMazer is based on [Lucas Tulio’s maze generation algorithms](https://github.com/lucas-tulio/maze-generation-algorithms), it might end up being GPL-licensed. Regarding the latter, I don’t know how much effort it would take to add support for another rendering backend, or to hook into a Linux-compatible screensaver framework...